# Zend Framework 2 instantiate table in Model

Tags: php, database, zend-framework2

I have a Model, called Admin with custom functions.

```
<?php

namespace ZendCustom\Model;

use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;
use Zend\Db\Exception\ErrorException;

abstract class Admin {

/**
 * @var TableGateway
 */
protected $_table;

/**
 * @var array 
 */
protected $data;

/**
 * @var bool
 */
protected $loaded = false;

/**
 * Constructor
 * 
 * @param array $data
 * @throws Exception
 */
public function __construct(array $data = array()) {
    if (!is_null($this->_table)) {
        if (!empty($data)) {
            $this->loaded = !empty($this->data);
        }
    } else {
        die('Please, specify table for ' . __CLASS__);
    }
}
}
```

And docs says to describe table, we should use:

```
// module/Album/src/Album/Controller/AlbumController.php:
    public function getAlbumTable()
    {
        if (!$this->albumTable) {
            $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
            $this->albumTable = $sm->get('Album\Model\AlbumTable');
        }
        return $this->albumTable;
    }
```

http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/database-and-models.html

How could I set my Model Table inside Admin Model, without Controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just inject it when it's instantiated via the Service Manager.

Module.php

```
/**
 * Get the service Config
 * 
 * @return array 
 */
public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
             'ZendCustom\Model\AdminSubclass' =>  function($sm) {
                // obviously you will need to extend your Admin class
                // as it's abstract and cant be instantiated directly
                $model= new \ZendCustom\Model\AdminSublcass();
                $model->setAlbumTable($sm->get('Album\Model\AlbumTable'));
                return $model;
            },
        )
    )
}
```

Admin.php

```
abstract class Admin {

    protected $_albumTable;

    /**
     * @param  \Album\Model\AlbumTable
     */
    public function setAlbumTable($ablum)
    {
        this->_albumTable = $ablum;
    }
}
```

Now if you want your Admin class (or a sublcass of it rather..) then you use the Service Manage to get the instance, and it will inject the Table Object you wanted..

Inside a controller you could do this:

```
$admin = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('ZendCustom\Model\AdminSubclass');
```

Comment: Thanks, that's work! But what about a couple of Models. Should I create injections per each of them?

Comment: sure, or you could just pass through the service locator itself it's your choice :)